# Rails, array of objects form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm developing a rails application.

I want the user to be able to make a selection between an array of models

In one controller, I create an array of models.

```
def myController
 @data = []
 @data += [MyData.find(2)]
 @data += [MyData.find(5)]
 @data += [MyData.find(7)]
end
```

In the view, I can't use the form_for because can't be used in an array, so I have:

```
<%= form_tag 'myOp' do |f|%>
 <%= fields_for :test, @data do |builder|%>
  <%= render 'sub_form', :f => builder %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Now in the sub_form, I want to recieve each of the items of the array, but instead, I'm getting the full array.

How can I get each of the items of the array in the subform?

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### So first in your controller

```
def my_action
    @datas = MyData.find(2, 5, 7)
end
```

### Then in your view

You need to iterate through the `@datas` array and yield the fields for each object. That is because `fields_for` yields fields for one object only, not arrays of objects.

```
<%= form_tag 'myOp' do |f|%>
    <% @datas.each_with_index do |data, i| %>
        <%= fields_for "test_#{i}", data do |builder|%>
            <%= render 'sub_form', :f => builder %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: .@data = []
.@data += [MyData.find(2)]
.@data += [MyData.find(5)]
.@data += [MyData.find(7)] is an array of objects. Not an array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will correct the issue:

```
<%= form_tag 'myOp' do |f|%>
 <%= fields_for :test, @data.each do |builder|%>
  <%= render 'sub_form', :f => builder %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Normally an array object can be seperated using **.each** method. May that would work here also. Try it.

Comment: The code that I posted usually workd on a form_for. The one that you posted is not working. The subform is recieving an Enumerator.

Comment: It works as describe here, but it is necessary to allow the owning model of form 'f' to access the data attributes in order to be able to add fields to form 'builder'. Took me quite a while to find that gap in my program.

    has_many :datas,
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :datas